# Execution failed for task ':@react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, react-native, compiler-errors

Suddenly, my application is not running the debug. When I try to run:
```
npx react-native run-android
```

It seems that it stops when the first library is scanned (I am not sure if that is the world) to agregate the apk.

> Task :@react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':@react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

My package.json configuration:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "8.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^15.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^15.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^15.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^15.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/functions": "^15.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.6.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "^15.6.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "3.4.3",
    "moment": "2.29.3",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.3",
    "react-native-calendars": "1.259.0",
    "react-native-code-push": "6.0.0",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.14.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-keychain": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^7.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-native": "^5.1.2",
    "realm": "6.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
```

I've already tried to restart my computer, clean the gradle (cd android && ./gradle clean), clean gradle cash (rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches) , debug through (./gradlew assembleDebug --info). But i keep getting the same error. What should I do?